# how to make the changes in the local directory reflect in command line for an npm module?

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I wish to contribute to [cordova-lib](https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib)

I git cloned the repositories and followed the steps mentioned here : https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib#setup

But the problem is that I am not able to reflect the changes I make in the code in local directory to the output.

That is , output remains same irrespective of whatever changes I make in the local directory ( one which I git cloned) .

Any suggestions of what should I do or check to avoid this ?

Comment: Have you read http://cordova.apache.org/#contribute?

Comment: yup, but it doesnt mention much :(

Comment: `To share your contributions with the community, you can send a pull request on GitHub to the Apache git mirrors. You can also advocate for your changes directly on our developer mailing list.` Seems like you need to wait for their response after following this part.

Comment: what I wish to do is to first try out the changes I make on my computer itself, so for that I need to run the changed code and not the one on the cordova repositories, but problem is I am not able to run the changed code on my local computer, it always runs whats their on the repository, how to make npm point to my changed code and run it so that I can see my changes ?